# How can I solve the Import error for scraping

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Unable to solve the error.
All the code is taken from the website, but it's not working.
This working environment is jupyter notebook because I tried to work at IDLE in desktop, but it was not worked.
I've tried to install scraping in my computer and succussed.
But still the error is not deleted.

Error messages:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 5>()
      2 get_ipython().run_line_magic('autoreload', '2')
      4 from datetime import datetime
----> 5 from scraping import Scraping
      6 from complete import Complete
      7 from train import Tree_updown, Tree_updown_k

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraiping'
```

Code that is generating the error:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

from datetime import datetime
from scraping import Scraping
from complete import Complete
from train import Tree_updown, Tree_updown_k
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says, `No module named 'scraiping'` but in your code you correctly imported scraping. So I suppose you just entered a typo while copying the error.

To fix it you just have to install the package. Type this in your terminal:

```
pip install scraping
```

Comment: If this solves your issue please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer